# Use inotifywait to monitor folders and run script on a file when found

Tags: bash, inotify

I am hoping someone could help me out. I am using a script that when pointed at a certain file in a folder, will generate a JSON file in that same folder. Below is the command used to run the script which is currently done file by file.

```
bash /path/to/script/PageBuilder.sh "/path/to/file/cvinfo"
```

I am looking to `inotifywait` to scan through the subdirectory and look for every `cvinfo` file and execute the script on that file.

This is what I have tried so far with no luck:

```bash
psttern="cvinfo"
inotifywait -m -r -e close_write --format %w%f /mnt/m/Comics/ | while read FILENAME; do
  if [[ "$FILENAME" == *${pattern}* ]]; then
    bash /mnt/m/PageBuilder/PageBuilder.sh "$FILENAME";
  fi
done&
```

This currently just sets up the watches and then nothing after that, even if the `cvinfo` file is moved to and from the folder or edited etc.

My knowledge on any of this is purely from our friend Google so i only have a very basic knowledge of how this works. I've tried looking for other posts to help but none work for my problem.

I'm using Windows but running this in a BASH terminal.

Comment: As I understood it, `inotify` has been made available under Windows only recently (Windows 10, don't know which patchlevel).

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this? I've looked at inotifywait and can get it to run on a single diredtory but could never get it to scan directories and run recursively. with just inotifywait -qm --event modify --format '%w' "/mnt/b/Action Lab/Twin Worlds (2020)/cvinfo" I've tried your script but i keep getting a syntax error.

Comment: To be honest: no. I've never tried it recursively.

Comment: From the man page, information about changed files is produced on stdout, according to a default pattern, at the time of the change.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on this while looking into a related topic... I realize this is an old post but it looks like you had a typo in the shell variable (`psttern` instead of `pattern`).

I'm not enough of an expert to know how that would fail without testing it myself, but it might fail silently (and since the `${pattern}` variable might not be initialized, it would return true for any `$FILENAME`).